# How to join/merge two generators output using python

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I have two generators g1 and g2

```
for line in g1:
    print line[0]
```

[a, a, a]
[b, b, b]
[c, c, c]

```
for line1 in g2:
    print line1[0]
```

[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]

```
for line in itertools.chain(g1, g2):
    print line[0]
```

[a, a, a]
[b, b, b]
[c, c, c]
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]

How

do I get the output like:
[a, a, a],[1, 1, 1]
[b, b, b],[2, 2, 2]
[c, c, c],[3, 3, 3]
or

[a, a, a, 1, 1, 1]
[b, b, b, 2, 2, 2]
[c, c, c, 3, 3, 3]

Thank You for Your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

first case: use

```
for x, y in zip(g1, g2):
    print(x[0], y[0])
```

second case: use

```
for x, y in zip(g1, g2):
    print(x[0] + y[0])
```

You can of course use `itertools.izip` for the generator version. You get the generator automatically if you use `zip` in Python 3 and greater.

Comment: Thanks! I'm iterating over a list and a generator altogether simultaneously. It's good to know I'm not wasting my generator.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for example

```
g1=([s]*3 for s in string.ascii_lowercase)
g2=([s]*3 for s in string.ascii_uppercase)
g=itertools.izip(g1,g2)
```

This will ensure the resultant is also a generator.

If you prefer to use the second here is how you can do it

```
g1=([s]*3 for s in string.ascii_lowercase)
g2=([s]*3 for s in string.ascii_uppercase)
g=(x+y for x,y in itertools.izip(g1,g2))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get pairs of things (your first request) using `zip(g1, g2)`. You can join them (your second request) by doing `[a + b for a, b in zip(g1, g2)]`.

Almost equivalently, you can use `map`. Use `map(None, g1, g2)` to produce a list of pairs, and `map(lambda x, y: x + y, g1, g2)` to join the pairs together.

In your examples, your generators are producing a list or tuple each time, of which you're only interested in the first element. I'd just generate the thing you need, or preprocess them before zipping or mapping them. For example:

```
g1 = (g[0] for g in g1)
g2 = (g[0] for g in g2)
```

Alternatively, you can apply [0] in the map. Here's the two cases:

```
map(lambda x, y: (x[0], y[0]), g1, g2)
map(lambda x, y: x[0] + y[0], g1, g2)
```

Comment: You missed the `[0]` in the examples.

Comment: how memory goes with endless generators ? what about using izip ?

Comment: @joaquin Yes, you can replace map and zip with itertools.imap and itertools.izip if you know the generators are large or infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have `g1` and `g2` :

```
g1 = [
    [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['e', 'e'], ['f', 'g']],
    [['b', 'b', 'b'], ['e', 'e'], ['f', 'g']],
    [['c', 'c', 'c'], ['e', 'e'], ['f', 'g']],
]

g2 = [
    [[1, 1, 1], ['t', 'q'], ['h', 't']],
    [[2, 2, 2], ['r', 'a'], ['l', 'o']],
    [[3, 3, 3], ['x', 'w'], ['z', 'p']],
]
```

To get that :

```
[a, a, a],[1, 1, 1]
[b, b, b],[2, 2, 2]
[c, c, c],[3, 3, 3]
```

You can do that :

```
result1 = map(lambda a, b: (a[0], b[0]) , g1, g2)
# Which is like this :
[(['a', 'a', 'a'], [1, 1, 1]),
 (['b', 'b', 'b'], [2, 2, 2]),  
 (['c', 'c', 'c'], [3, 3, 3])]
```

And for the second :

```
[a, a, a, 1, 1, 1]
[b, b, b, 2, 2, 2]
[c, c, c, 3, 3, 3]

result2 = map(lambda a, b: a[0]+b[0] , g1, g2)
# Which is like that :
[['a', 'a', 'a', 1, 1, 1],
 ['b', 'b', 'b', 2, 2, 2],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', 3, 3, 3]]
```